# What all threats imposed by an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

**Case :**

i m developing a client side website which shows iframes to users and the urls are not in my control or are different from my domain

for example

my domain is `https://example.com` and the domain of iframe is `https://random.app.example.com`. the other domain content is handled by random users

**What i have done :**

so in order to stop the abuse i have sandboxed the iframe like this

`sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms"`

as of my research and knowledge this much sandboxing gives enough power to the iframe but not enough to exploit the parent site.

i have wrapped up things very quick so i might have missed things

**Real Question :**

so just to make sure i want to know if there are any threats left in this approach and also please mention the solution to overcome the threat

any kind of suggestion is welcomed please help

Comment: this question is not duplicate. read it again whoever flagged this as duplicate

Comment: I'm not sure how the duplicate does not answer your question. Specifically, "*you're basically trusting that domain not to serve-up malware.*" and "*A correctly implemented browsers (a.k.a. User Agent) will not allow the iframe contents to leak outside the iframe.*"

Comment: @Bergi well, i have already sandboxed the iframe because i dont know what the user would serve in that iframe thats why i have asked a specific question => is there still any threat in my appraoch ? please unflag it if you can

Comment: A threat to do what specifically? No, your site's dom is safe and always was, but of course the iframe still might serve bad content (containing malware, tricking users into doing things they shouldn't, etc.). I'm not going to reopen.

Comment: @Bergi no prob enjoy thnx